# Passing binary data from php to java with custom web-service

Tags: java, php, web-services, binary-data

I have created a php service which sends an array containg file name and file contents(in binary),
I have done the http_build_query of the array and sending the data

But when I read the data from java client I am not able to decode file content (which was in binary)

can someone suggest a solution for the same, my objective is to send an array containg file name and content(binary) from php service which will be consumed by java client over apache as web server

thanks in advance

Comment: since you have created web-service. Why stuck to binary still?
use xml or json.

Comment: thanks vaibhav, I have to pass image and other media content(which is actually binary data) with file name... If I send it as json or xml then the content is decoded as blank as we cannot decode binary data...

Comment: are you using base64 encode decode ?

Comment: base64 encode increases the size ... also I want some generic solution..